# Running SonarQube with Docker in CI/CD pipeline

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, docker, sonarqube, docker-compose

I'm trying to get SonarQube stood up and scanning applications via Docker containers on an EC2 instance.  I've spent the past day poring over SonarQube and Postgres documentation and am having very little luck.

The most sensible guide I've found is the [docker-sonarqube project](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube) maintained by SonarSource.  More specifically, I am following the [SonarQube/Postgres guide using docker-compose](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/master/recipes.md).

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks identical to the one provided by SonarSource:

```
sonarqube:
  build: "5.2"
  ports:
   - "9000:9000"
  links:
   - db
  environment:
   - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
  volumes_from:
   - plugins

db:
  image: postgres
  volumes_from:
    - datadb
  environment:
   - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
   - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar

datadb:
  image: postgres
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql
  command: /bin/true

plugins:
  build: "5.2"
  volumes:
   - /opt/sonarqube/extensions
   - /opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins
  command: /bin/true
```

`docker ps -a` yields:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                           PORTS                    NAMES
2d003aef18f2        dockersonarqube_sonarqube   "./bin/run.sh"           47 seconds ago      Up 46 seconds                    0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp   dockersonarqube_sonarqube_1
c7d5043f4381        dockersonarqube_plugins     "./bin/run.sh /bin/tr"   48 seconds ago      Exited (0) 46 seconds ago                                 dockersonarqube_plugins_1
590c72b4a723        postgres                    "/docker-entrypoint.s"   48 seconds ago      Up 47 seconds                    5432/tcp                 dockersonarqube_db_1
c105e6aebe09        postgres                    "/docker-entrypoint.s"   49 seconds ago      Exited (0) 48 seconds ago                                 dockersonarqube_datadb_1
```

Latest output from the sonarqube_1 container is:

```
sonarqube_1 | 2016.01.20 17:49:09 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
sonarqube_1 | 2016.01.20 17:49:09 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
sonarqube_1 | 2016.01.20 17:49:09 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
```

What does concern me is the latest output from the db_1 container:

```
PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

LOG:  database system was shut down at 2016-01-20 17:48:40 UTC
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
ERROR:  relation "schema_migrations" does not exist at character 21
STATEMENT:  select version from schema_migrations
ERROR:  relation "schema_migrations" does not exist at character 21
STATEMENT:  select version from schema_migrations
ERROR:  relation "schema_migrations" does not exist at character 21
STATEMENT:  select version from schema_migrations
ERROR:  relation "schema_info" does not exist at character 15
STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM "schema_info"  LIMIT 1
```

Navigating to http://my.instance.ip:9000 is unsuccessful.  I am able to hit the respective ports of other running containers from the same machine.

Could anyone help to point me in the right direction?  Any other guides or documentation that may serve me better?  I also see issues with the documentation stating that analyzing a project begins with `mvn sonar:sonar`, but I'll defer that for now.  Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

[Use this image](https://github.com/million12/docker-sonar)
I modified this image to talk to a RDS instance.

EC2(docker-sonar)<==> RDS postgres